# Ansible Nested lists into jinja template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am attempting to past a nested list into jinja to create a configuration file for Telegraf using the SNMP input plug-in.

So far I have  been able to parse the following simple list into a suitable configuration file.

List:

```
    - name: CpuUsage
      oid: 1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.1.41.1.0
    - name: mgmt_CPU
      oid: 1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.1.41.6.1.2.8.77.103.109.116.32.67.80.85
    - name: MemUsage
      oid: 1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.1.41.2.0
    - name: TotRxMbits
      oid: 1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.1.43.27.0
    - name: TotTxMbits
      oid: 1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.1.43.30.0
    - name: httpTotRequestsRate
      oid: 1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.1.48.76.0
    - name: tcpCurClientConnEstablished
      oid: 1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.1.46.12.0
    - name: tcpCurServerConnEstablished
      oid: 1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.1.46.10.0
    - name: tcpCurClientConnClosing
      oid: 1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.1.46.9.0
```

into the following config:

```
  [[inputs.snmp.field]]
    name = "CpuUsage"
    oid = "1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.1.41.1.0"
    conversion = "int"
  [[inputs.snmp.field]]
    name = "mgmt_CPU"
    oid = "1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.1.41.6.1.2.8.77.103.109.116.32.67.80.85"
    conversion = "int"
  [[inputs.snmp.field]]
    name = "MemUsage"
    oid = "1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.1.41.2.0"
    conversion = "int"
  [[inputs.snmp.field]]
    name = "TotRxMbits"
    oid = "1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.1.43.27.0"
    conversion = "int"
  [[inputs.snmp.field]]
    name = "TotTxMbits"
    oid = "1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.1.43.30.0"
    conversion = "int"
  [[inputs.snmp.field]]
    name = "httpTotRequestsRate"
    oid = "1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.1.48.76.0"
    conversion = "int"
  [[inputs.snmp.field]]
    name = "tcpCurClientConnEstablished"
    oid = "1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.1.46.12.0"
    conversion = "int"
  [[inputs.snmp.field]]
    name = "tcpCurServerConnEstablished"
    oid = "1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.1.46.10.0"
    conversion = "int"
  [[inputs.snmp.field]]
    name = "tcpCurClientConnClosing"
    oid = "1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.1.46.9.0"
    conversion = "int"
```

Where I am stuck is with the following list of lists

```
netscaler_citrix_vserver:
  - name: name
    oid: NS-ROOT-MIB::vsvrName
    is_tag: "true"
  - name: fullName
    oid: NS-ROOT-MIB::vsvrFullName
    is_tag: "true"
  - name: requests
    oid: NS-ROOT-MIB::vsvrTotalRequests
  - name: state
    oid: NS-ROOT-MIB::vsvrState
  - name: servicesUp
    oid: NS-ROOT-MIB::vsvrCurServicesUp
netscaler_citrix_vservice:
  - name: vserver
    oid: NS-ROOT-MIB::vserverFullName
    is_tag: "true"
  - name: vservice
    oid: NS-ROOT-MIB::vsvrServiceFullName
    is_tag: "true"
  - name: hits
    oid: NS-ROOT-MIB::vsvrServiceHits
```

I've tried a number of variations, but each proving unsuccessful. I'm trying to get the following output:

```
[[inputs.snmp.table]]
    name = "netscaler_citrix_vserver"
    # oid omitted, to allow collection of specific columns only
    [[inputs.snmp.table.field]]
      name = "name"
      oid = "NS-ROOT-MIB::vsvrName"
      is_tag = true
    [[inputs.snmp.table.field]]
      name = "fullName"
      oid = "NS-ROOT-MIB::vsvrFullName"
      is_tag = true
    [[inputs.snmp.table.field]]
      name = "requests"
      oid = "NS-ROOT-MIB::vsvrTotalRequests"
    [[inputs.snmp.table.field]]
      name = "state"
      oid = "NS-ROOT-MIB::vsvrState"
    [[inputs.snmp.table.field]]
      name = "servicesUp"
      oid = "NS-ROOT-MIB::vsvrCurServicesUp"


  [[inputs.snmp.table]]
    name = "netscaler_citrix_vservice"
    # oid omitted, to allow collection of specific columns only
    [[inputs.snmp.table.field]]
      name = "vserver"
      oid = "NS-ROOT-MIB::vserverFullName"
      is_tag = true
    [[inputs.snmp.table.field]]
      name = "vservice"
      oid = "NS-ROOT-MIB::vsvrServiceFullName"
      is_tag = true
    [[inputs.snmp.table.field]]
      name = "hits"
      oid = "NS-ROOT-MIB::vsvrServiceHits"
```

Basically I need to reference the top-level entry and for each top-level entry list the sub-level entries also.

Any help would be appreciated.

the code used to create the first list is pretty straightforward, as follows:

```
[[inputs.snmp.field]]
name = "{{ item.name }}"
oid = "{{ item.oid }}"
{% endfor %}
```

for the SNMP table code I've resorted to explicitly declaring the table name as follows:

```
[[inputs.snmp.table]]
  name = "netscaler_citrix_vserver"
{% for item in netscaler_citrix_vserver %}
[[inputs.snmp.table.field]]
  name = "{{ item.name }}"
  oid = "{{ item.oid }}"
{% if item.is_tag is defined %}
  is_tag = {{item.is_tag}}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

[[inputs.snmp.table]]
  name = "netscaler_citrix_vservice"
{% for item in netscaler_citrix_vservice %}
[[inputs.snmp.table.field]]
  name = "{{ item.name }}"
  oid = "{{ item.oid }}"
{% if item.is_tag is defined %}
  is_tag = {{item.is_tag}}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I noticed your question does not have any of your code in it. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section since. Good luck

Comment: thanks, added my code for the list, but I've tried so many variations for the nested list I've lost track.

Answer (score 0):

Of course as soon as I posted the answer from another question in related questions popped up. Resolved with the following code

````
{% for input_snmp_table in input_snmp_tables recursive %}
[[inputs.snmp.table]]
  name = {{ input_snmp_table.table_name }}
{% for input_snmp_table_fields in input_snmp_table.input_snmp_table_fields %}
[[inputs.snmp.table.field]]
  name = "{{ input_snmp_table_fields.name }}"
  oid = "{{ input_snmp_table_fields.oid}}"
{% if input_snmp_table_fields.is_tag is defined %}
  is_tag = {{input_snmp_table_fields.is_tag}}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}```
````